# How do I get the coordinates of a rotated shape in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to get collisions of bullets working, and am using SFML. I am using code to get the position of the points of the rectangle for collisions, however I think there's a way to do this without having to get points but by simply getting the points from SFML, since the shape is a rectangle and the points are stored in that way. Is there a way to do that? Through a combination of `getPoint()` and `getGlobalBounds()` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

1. use getLocalBound of sprite
2. Get transform of sprite
3. use transformPoint of that transform to transform a point to its rotated coords

Also you can visit my post on SFML forums:

http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=12604.0

Comment: lol, nice coincidence since I was the one answering your post in the forum x)